# Passing a value, retrieved from a linq statement in a view, to its controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a view that has c# and linq in it(not ideal but I have to work with it!):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 .
 .
var qry = (from p in db.EntityObject
                       where something == something_else
                       select new
                            {
                                <fields>
                            }).FirstOrDefault();
 .
 .
}
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
.
.
```

I need to pass a value that is retrieved via a linq statement in the view to my controller.  I've tried this:

```
 var qry = (from <entity objects>       
 select new
                        {
                            id,
                            // fields
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
 RouteData.Values.Add("id", qry.id);
```

Then I tried to pass it to a hidden input type as a value:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%Int32.Parse(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString())"/>
```

but, when I use Chrome's tools to view the input element the 'value' is empty.  I don't know of a way to pass a field retrived from linq in a view to it's corresponding action in the controller.

My view is strongly typed based on a table in the entity framework and the 'id' that I want to pass, from the view to controller, is not in that table.  I don't want to create a model, just for one extra field, unless I have to.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The linq query is in your View? Then, why do you add it to RouteData? I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: clarify your code parts. make sure you have passes data to view.

Comment: ataravati - I've edited my question and made some additional comments which I hope makes it clear what I'm trying to do.  If you didn't know what I was trying to achieve then perhaps you shouldn't have tried to answer it.  Yes I can create a model but, for just one extra value, I'm looking for a way to avoid it.  AmirHossein - ironic that you ask me to clarify when you post "make sure you have passes data to view.".  I don't mean to be offensive.  I realise my question wasn't as clear as it could have been but I think it was clear enough as to what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it looks like you're trying to obtain a value in your *view* and make that value available to code running in your *controller*. The view has a handle to the controller through `ViewContext.Controller`, which you can cast to the type of your controller and then interact with. For example, you could add a property to your controller and then set it from the view. I'm not sure why you would do that, because the controller's job is usually done by the time the view is rendering, but it's an option if you want to pursue it.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Yes, that would work.  The reason I'm passing a value from view back to the controller may sound as backward to you as it is to me.  I should have explained I have a button on the view that links back to the same action in the controller.  The data that populates the view comes from the Page_Load method which is also in the view itself (yes, I know).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel, and make your View strongly-typed based on the ViewModel. Your ViewModel can be something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your View, you'll have:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) %>
```